# Why destructor of a moved from object is invoked?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

Consider the following piece of code:

```
struct foo {
  std::string id;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<foo> v;

  {
    foo tmp;
    v.push_back(std::move(tmp));
  }
}
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd5ab085542c15a7)

In the piece of code demonstrated:

1. The default constructor of class `foo` is going to be invoked for the construction of object `tmp`.
2. The move constructor of class `foo` is going to be invoked in the statement `v.push_back(std::move(tmp));`.
3. **The destructor of `class foo` is going to be invoked twice.**

**Questions:**

1. Why the destructor of a moved from object is called twice?
2. What is moved from the object that is being moved really?

Comment: The moved-from object is only destructed once. Every object is created once and destructed once.  The two destructor calls are for `tmp`, and the object in the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the destructor of a moved object is called twice?

The first destructor destroys the moved-from `tmp` when it goes out of scope at the first `}` in `main()`. The second destructor destroys the move-constructed `foo` that you `push_back`'d into `v` at the end of `main()` when `v` goes out of scope.

> What is moved from the object that is being moved really?

The compiler-generated move constructor move-constructs `id`, which is a `std::string`. A move constructor of `std::string` typically takes ownership of the block of memory in the moved-from object storing the actual string, and sets the moved-from object to a valid but unspecified state (in practice, likely an empty string).

Comment: "destroys tmp, after it's been moved from": 
Well, it gets destroyed by virtue of leaving the scope (the `}` after the push_back), not immediately after it has been moved from (the `;` after the push_back).  This matters if there is more code between the `push_back` and the `}`.

Comment: @AndreKostur I wasn't intending to imply that there's a casual connection between `tmp` being moved from and `tmp` being destroyed; that was intended to explain why the first destructor output in the OP's demo printed out an empty string, and describe the state of `tmp` at the time of its destruction. I see that it can be confusing, though, so clarified.